# NSPanel Sheet Not Receiving Mouse Events

Tags: objective-c, macos, mouseevent, nswindow, nsbutton

**SIMPLIFIED:**

I have the following:

1. `NSWindow` (this is the main window of the app)
2. `NSPanel` (this is presented as a sheet, over the main `NSWindow`, using `[NSApp beginSheet:`)
3. The main `NSWindow` has a subclassed `NSButton` that uses mouse events, including `mouseEntered`, `mouseExited`. This changes the background color of the button as I hover over it.
4. I present my `NSPanel`, this also has an `NSButton` of the same subclass, to change color on hover.
5. Mouse events still occur in the main `NSWindow` while my `NSPanel` is presented. I can tell this, as hovering over the buttons still works.
6. However, hovering over the buttons in the presented `NSPanel` does not work, despite them being no different from the other buttons. I can click on them and they receive an action. But they do not call the mouse events.

**ORIGINAL:**

I have a simple setup in my Mac app. I have a main NSWindow, as any usual mac app, then I run the following code which displays my detail view.

My detail view is an `NSWindowController` subclass and I am displaying it as a sheet. This is setup as an `NSPanel` in the xib and just displays a detail view for me over my main window.

```
APDetailWindowController *vc = [[APDetailWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"APDetailWindowController"];
    self.detailWindowController = vc;
    
    self.detailWindowController.delegate = self;
    
    APAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [NSApp beginSheet:self.detailWindowController.window modalForWindow:appDelegate.window modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
```

In my main window (of the AppDelegate), I have my views played out as any app, including some NSButtons. These buttons are subclassed so that when they receive `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` events, they change colour. Basically creating a rollover effect.

In my detail view, I also have buttons of the same subclass. However, they are not receiving the mouse events at all. I can see when moving my mouse over them nothing happens. Even when the detail view is displayed, the rollover works on the main window buttons in the background, but not in my detail view.

I am thinking maybe some sort of focus is still on the main window and needs to be set to the detail window?

Comment: I'm worried that your panel is calling a different app delegate object than the main window, or the panel controller doesn't own the window... in other words, you shot yourself in the foot with IB somehow.   Any new news since you posted?